# if all product is in stock show or hide

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of products on an order, and I want to check if I stock these codes. If I have all the codes that are on my order to display if I do not have to hide order.

I have two tables. One with products from customer order, and one1 with products that are in stock in the store.

I want this MySql connection to show only the orders where I have all the products. If I don't have all the products, hide the order in list.

PHP

```
<?php while($row = $sql->fetch_array()){?>
    <tr id="row<?php echo $row['id'];?>" style="height:20px">
        <td><?php echo $row['id_comanda']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['nume_produs']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['qty']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['stoc']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } $DBcon->close();?>
```

MySql

```
SELECT c.id_comanda
    ,c.nume_produs
    ,c.qty
    ,s.sku
    ,SUM(s.stoc) as stoc
    FROM comenzi_tel_prod c
INNER JOIN stocuri_mentor s ON c.nume_produs = s.sku AND s.stoc >= c.qty
GROUP BY c.nume_produs


OR 

SELECT c.*
    ,s.*
    ,SUM(stoc) AS stoc
FROM comenzi_tel_prod c
INNER JOIN stocuri_mentor s ON c.nume_produs = s.sku
    AND stoc >= c.qty
GROUP BY c.id_comanda
```

The database:

```
    comenzi_tel_prod 

+----+------------+-------------+-----+-------+------------+----------------------------------------+--------------+----------+
| id | id_comanda | nume_produs | qty | price | pret_engro |               nume_ales                |   furnizor   | subtotal |
+----+------------+-------------+-----+-------+------------+----------------------------------------+--------------+----------+
| 94 |         18 | K316546     |   2 | 17.85 |      16.16 | SUPER NET PURPLE 38cm x 38cm, EMGO, EA | Parts Europe |  523.719 |
| 95 |         18 | K316539     |   1 | 14.67 |      13.28 | SUPER NET-BLACK 38cm x 38cm, EMGO, EA  | Parts Europe |    14.67 |
+----+------------+-------------+-----+-------+------------+----------------------------------------+--------------+----------+



    stocuri_mentor

+----+---------+---------------------------------------+--------+------+---------------+------------+-----------+-----------+-------+--------------------+--------------+-----+---------------+
| id |   sku   |                 nume                  | den_um | stoc | stoc_rezervat | pret_engro | sim_clasa | den_clasa | brand |      furnizor      | pret_vanzare | gol |      ean      |
+----+---------+---------------------------------------+--------+------+---------------+------------+-----------+-----------+-------+--------------------+--------------+-----+---------------+
|  1 | K316539 | Arc ambreaj pornire Piaggio Ciao/Si   | Buc    |    1 |             0 |       0,87 | CIF       | CIF       | CIF   | MOTO BIKE SHOP SRL |         1,04 |     | 6686245374874 |
|  2 | K316546 | Paleta racire variator Piaggio/Gilera | Buc    |    1 |             0 |      35,64 | CIF       | CIF       | CIF   | MOTO BIKE SHOP SRL |        42,41 |     | 6686245375017 |
|  3 | 11503   | Cui ponto scuter carburator PHBN/PHVA | Buc    |    0 |             0 |      23,23 | CIF       | CIF       | Cif   | MOTO BIKE SHOP SRL |        27,64 |     | 6686245375093 |
|  4 | 11503   | Cui ponto scuter carburator PHBN/PHVA | Buc    |    1 |             0 |      23,23 | CIF       | CIF       | Cif   | MOTO BIKE SHOP SRL |        27,64 |     | 6686245375093 |
|  5 | 0531z11 | Pinion z11 Garelli                    | Buc    |    1 |             0 |       24,5 | CIF       | CIF       | CIF   | MOTO BIKE SHOP SRL |        29,16 |     | 6686245375246 |
|  6 | 11507   | Filtru holender Piaggio               | Buc    |    3 |             0 |       9,11 | CIF       | CIF       | CIF   | MOTO BIKE SHOP SRL |        10,84 |     | 6686245470590 |
+----+---------+---------------------------------------+--------+------+---------------+------------+-----------+-----------+-------+--------------------+--------------+-----+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 `SELECT c.*
      ,s.*
      ,count(c.id) as instock_count
      ,totals.orders_total

  FROM comenzi_tel_prod c
  INNER JOIN (SELECT *, sum(stoc) as stoc_sum
                FROM stocuri_mentor GROUP BY 
                 sku ) s
     ON c.nume_produs = s.sku
  INNER JOIN (SELECT count(id) as orders_total, id_comanda 
               FROM comenzi_tel_prod 
                GROUP BY id_comanda ) totals
     ON totals.id_comanda = c.id_comanda 

  WHERE stoc_sum >= c.qty
  GROUP BY c.id_comanda
  HAVING instock_count = orders_total`
```

Comment: It works great after we've changed * ,SUM(stoc) as stoc_sum .